# Limit UserForm Scrollbar to certain values

Tags: vba, excel, scrollbar, userform

I'm building a UserForm in VBA and I have a scrollbar for the user to select a certain value.

As the minimum is 100 and the maximum is 10000, I would only like the scrollbar to be able to achieve values between these in steps of 50.

I know that you can set smallchange and largechange, but if the scrollbar is dragged it seems to go up in increments of 1.

Is it possible to change this?
Or should I give up trying?

Comment: Just want to make sure you know how these scrollbars work: (1) click on the arrow to the top `-->` Small Change (2) click on the bar (not on the arrows and not on the current marker) `-->` Large Change (3) click on the marker and drag it `-->` changes by increments of one.

Comment: So you can never change the incrementation of clicking on the marker and dragging it?

Comment: Oh boy, someone has difficulties answering a question without being oddly insulting first. But it seems you need it. Thank you for the answer, it has actually been very helpful and will aid in making the user interface of my project more friendly. Done.

Answer (score 0):

On the properties window of scrollbar (in the left), you should have LargeChange=1 change that to 50 and should work.